# Simple slideshow in a UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, slideshow

I got trouble to add slideshow to my application.

Currently, I have a UIView composed of a segmentedControl.
I made ​​two "views" that I hide or display depending on the selected button.

I'm looking to make a simple slideshow in one of my two views. I made a UIImageView because it is simple to display pictures.

So I'd like to display my pictures one by one and it is possible to move from one image to another by sliding your finger to the right or left (just as in the native app "Photos").

I tried to adapt example codes from the documentation, but without succes.

So I'ml looking for help.

Thanks,
jb crestot

Answer (score -3, accepted):

See apple's page control sample application.

Answer (score 1):

SO, I've actually done this and it's fairly easy. The ingredient that you are missing is a UISCrollView. My implementation did exactly what you describe (allow the user to go back and forth between a set of images).

Basically, add a UIScrollView to your View in interface builder and you will be creating the UIImage views with code (a simple for loop) and setting their images the same way. I did this safely with no memories issues with about 15 images (PNG's). There could be a potential performance issue with this message if you are working with a large number of images (say 40?)

I hope this helps, let me know if you need a code sample to see how this works.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using a custom class, such as iCarousel, linked below. Each of these views could be your image, and then tapping on them could launch a fullscreen view for example.

Keep us posted!

http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/icarousel